# MySQL cause Blue Screen (UNEXPECTED KERNEL MODE TRAP) when trying to change users schemas privileges

Tags: mysql, blue-screen-of-death

My PC produce a Blue Screen Of Death with an UNEXPECTED KERNEL MODE TRAP stop code every time I tried to add an entry to a user schemas privileges in MySql Workbench 6.3 CE. I need to give this user permission to access this schema. What shall I do?

Specs.: I have a Windows 10 workstation with an Intel i7 processor and 12GB of DDR3 RAM.

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same problem!
No solution found so far...

For a workaround you could try PHPMyAdmin or set the persmission directly via console.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem. Here you can found the official bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86606. For now there is no solution